# What does "来" mean in "如果你不按照安全手续来的话，你可能会受伤的。"?

Tags: translation, grammar, ambiguity

What does "来" mean in "如果你不按照安全手续来的话，你可能会受伤的.

I usually have some sort of idea with these things, even when I'm wrong. But with this, I have no clue at all.

Thanks so much!!! This is a great resource!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This use of 来 ***replaces the actual verb***.

Here is the dictionary definition:

> 表示做某个动作（代替意义具体的动词）

So your sentence can be paraphrased as 如果你不按照安全手续***办***(/***做***)的话，你可能会受伤的.

Other examples: 你搬不动，我来吧。== 你搬不动，我搬吧。

Answer (score 6):

This sentence is the abbreviation of 如果你不按照安全手续来"做"的话，你可能会受伤的.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, it means `follow`.

> 如果你不**按照**安全手续**来**的话，你可能会受伤的。
> If you do not **follow** the safety procedures, you may be injured.

***The following content is not rigorous, only for easier understand.***

The basic means of `来` is `come to (here)`. The antisense of `去`, `go to (there)`.

> 到我家**来**。
> **Come to** my home.

`来` in this example means **someone's `position` will come to my home**.
`来` in your example means **your `operate` will come to the goal of safety procedures**.

> 如果你不**按照**安全手续**来**的话，你可能会受伤的。
> 如果你不**按照**安全手续**操作**的话，你可能会受伤的。

Answer (score 1):

I think `來` here is similar with `go with` or `follow` in English.
Like:

> If you don't `follow` the rule, you'll get hurt.

Answer (score 1):

來 = Do it that follow the (mentioned) way

Answer (score 1):

As was said above, 来 replaces a verb, and as your question suggsts ambiguity, perhaps it isn't integral to the meaning, and possibly debatably redundant if taken further:

如果你不按照安全手续来"做/操作"的话，你可能会受伤的.. (extension)

如果你不按照安全手续来的话，你可能会受伤 (original)

如果你不按照安全手续.. 你会受伤. (abridged)

But here, 安全手[续](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%BB%AD/5164431)+来+的话 it ties bound units, as in
... 续, 来,看,来,听,来过来出来进来回来起来用来, 的 dynamically, and perhaps predicating the omitted.